# How to import a map image from OSM to Blender?

Tags: image, 2d, lineart

How could I import an image of a map from Open Street Maps to Blender? I'm not talking about 3D buildings or terrain. Rather, I'm talking about importing an image from the map itself into Blender as a flat surface/plane. 2D basically.

To give an example, I'd like to import the OSM map for Lexington, Massachusetts. So anything within its marked borders including labels and names. Is that possible?